# Extending Travis build time

Tags: travis-ci

I'm attempting to avoid travis timing out by adding `install: travis_wait 50 ...` to my build.  However travis gives the following error:

```
The command "npm test" exited with 0.
0.10s$ {:install=>"travis_wait 50 gulp deploy:test:css"}
{:install=: command not found
```

this is the [travis file](https://github.com/superflycss/utilities-colors/blob/master/.travis.yml)

I'm probably specifing the `install: ...` part wrong.  Thoughts?

Comment: What does the `.travis.yml` look like for that part?

Comment: It's linked in the travis file link in the question.

Comment: You may want to reorganize the file more sequentially. Anyway, I am not sure why your `before_deploy` value is being recognized as a `install` value by Travis. Additionally, Travis seems to not be able to find the path to `travis_wait`, so you can try specifying the full path. Fixing both or either of those will get you progress.

Comment: Also added a travis issue report here: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8697

Comment: I've tried adding install: travis_wait right before the deploy command, as indicated in the travis documentation, but that also failed.  I'm not sure where travis installs travis_wait ...